# Android Region Monitoring?

Tags: android, ios, region

Is there something similar in Android to the iOS version of region monitoring? I've only come across the Region class in Android, and I think to achieve something similar would require quite a bit of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Check ou this class :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html